# Refreshing a ListView in a User Control from another User Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, event-handling

I have two User Controls. Each User Control contains a ListView. The purpose of these two User Controls is to display master/detail data. When raising the event ResourceReassigned a null reference exception is always thrown. What am I doing wrong that means my event handler assignment is not working?

```
<asp:ListView ID="lvStaffer" runat="server">
  <LayoutTemplate>
    <table>
      <tr id="itemplaceholder" runat="server"></tr>
    </table>
  </LayoutTemplate>
  <ItemTemplate>
    <tr>
      <td>                    
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upResourceListViewControlItem" runat="server">
          <ContentTemplate>
            <rw:ResourceListViewControl ID="ResourceListViewControlItem" runat="server" />
          </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>


public partial class Control_ResourceListViewControl : StafferWebControlBase
{

  public event EventHandler ResourceReassigned;

  protected void lvResource_ItemUpdating(Object sender, ListViewUpdateEventArgs e)
  {
    // If an item in lvResource is updated we want to refresh the master lvStaffer
    // ListView so we raise an event. Null Reference Exception is thrown here. 
    ResourceReassigned(sender, new EventArgs());
  }

}

public partial class Control_StafferListViewControl : StafferWebControlBase
{

  protected void lvStaffer_ItemDataBound(Object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
  {
    Control_ResourceListViewControl resourceListViewControlItem =
(Control_ResourceListViewControl)e.Item.FindControl("ResourceListViewControlItem");

    if (resourceListViewControlItem != null)
    {
      // Each item in lvStaffer contains an instance of the ResourceListViewControl object.
      // Each object is a subscriber of the ResourceReassigned event.
      resourceListViewControlItem.ResourceReassigned += new EventHandler(lvStaffer_ResourceReassigned);
    }

  }

  protected void lvStaffer_ResourceReassigned(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    // Repopulates and binds the lvStaffer ListView
    ResetStafferListView();
  }

}
```

Comment: do you make  databind for listview  every time or only if page is not postback?

Comment: The lvStaffer ListView is bound only if page is not postback.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should bind your event everytime (not only if page is not post back).  For example on Page_Load event or  control OnLoad.

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){     
  foreach (ListViewItem item in lvStaffer.Items)
        {
           Control_ResourceListViewControl resourceListViewControlItem =
        (Control_ResourceListViewControl)e.Item.FindControl("ResourceListViewControlItem");

        if (resourceListViewControlItem != null)
        {
           // Each item in lvStaffer contains an instance of the          ResourceListViewControl object.
          // Each object is a subscriber of the ResourceReassigned event.
           resourceListViewControlItem.ResourceReassigned += new   EventHandler(lvStaffer_ResourceReassigned);
        }
       }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

The `NullReferenceException` is thrown because at the point of raising an event there are no subscribers on it. While you can safely call "RaiseEvent" in VB.NET, in C# you first need to check whether the event object is not `null`:

```
if (ResourceReassigned != null)
    ResourceReassigned(sender, EventArgs.Empty);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand that there are no subscribers and that I should first check if null. However I don't understand why there are no subscribers. Every instance of the ResourceListViewControlItem object has the lvStaffer_ResourceReassigned subscriber. This is specified in the ItemDataBound event hander of the lvStaffer ListView so this shouldn't be null as a subscriber should always be present.

Comment: @ernie99 I'd suggest that you use debugger to find out why call to "ItemUpdating" event handler is made prior the "ItemDataBound" handler of the parent control. I think it's something in the logic of your program.